# update an elasticsearch document

Tags: elasticsearch

This code is working as expected. But instead of adding the third country as another document, I want to update the first document.

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "parent": [
      {
         "name": "India",
         "label": "IN"
      },
      {
         "name": "China",
         "label": "CN"
      }
   ]
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
   "parent": [
      {
         "name": "Pakistan",
         "label": "PK"
      }
   ]
}
```

So that the Document ID 1 will have 3 countries India, China and Pakistan. I guess I need update API with doc_as_upsert parameter. But I am not sure how to write the JSON.

Comment: see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document

Comment: this document might be better: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html#_using_scripts_to_make_partial_updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a scripted updated using the [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates):

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test_index/doc/1/_update' -d '{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.parent += ['name': name, 'label': label]",
        "params" : {
            "name" : "Pakistan",
            "label": "PK"
        }
    }
}'
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to use this in a bulk query, it is also possible

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test_index/doc/_bulk' -d '
{ "update" : { "_id" : "1"} }
{ "script" : { "inline": "ctx._source.parent += ['name': name, 'label': label]", "lang" : "groovy", "params" : {"name" : "Pakistan", "label": "PK"}}}
'
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this in bulk API? Because my index has millions of records and a few thousand of them needs to be updated like this!

Comment: I am getting "document missing exception" if the ID 1 does not exist. Is it possible to create document 1 with that update query?

Comment: By definition, updating a document implies that the document exists. I thought you already had documents and you had to update them.

Comment: There are some cases where the document may not exist. I guess "doc_as_upsert" : true parameter will not work with script. Right?

Comment: I tried "upsert" and it is working as expected. Is there any advantage of mapping the "parent" as nested object?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to val's answer, I can use upsert if the document does not already exist.

```
POST /test_index/doc/1/_update
{
   "script": {
      "inline": "ctx._source.parent += ['name': name, 'label': label]",
      "params": {
         "name": "Pakistan",
         "label": "PK"
      }
   },
   "upsert": {"parent" : [{
      "name": "Pakistan",
      "label": "PK"
   }]
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Bulk API using upsert will look something like this...

```
POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{ "update" : { "_id" : "1"} }
{ "script" : { "inline": "ctx._source.parent += ['name': name, 'label': label]", "lang" : "groovy", "params" : {"name" : "Pakistan", "label": "PK"}}, "upsert": {"parent" : [{"name": "Pakistan", "label": "PK" }] }}
```