# How to delete inner indices data

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am working in elastic search and i have following array in elastic search

```
{
  "took": 101,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 24745,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "users",
        "_type": "user",
        "_id": "742",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
         {
    "id": "1",
    "username": "broad",
    "full_name": "Bradshaw",
    "age": 29,
    "gender": "Male",
    "followers" : ["2","3","4"]
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "username": "kevin",
    "full_name": "Kevin",
    "age": 29,
    "gender": "Male",
    "followers" : ["1","3"]
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "username": "john",
    "full_name": "John Smith",
    "age": 29,
    "gender": "Male",
    "followers" : ["1","2"]
},
.
.
. and so on
}
]}
```

Now I want to delete follower two from user 1. Now I am confuse that how I do this I search user 2 but I am unable to update followers of user 1 by delete follower 2 from follower list. Can anyone tell me that what will be the query string of this problem.

Comment: I would generalize your question like this:
**How can I do a partial update of an elasticsearch document?** 

For this question there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627213/update-an-elasticsearch-document), which is, basically, use [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/docs-update-by-query.html). In your case it might be too complicated so it is easier to patch the document on client side and send the new version to ES.

By the way, Node.js does not seem to be relevant to the question.